# Cause of lag spikes / svchost.exe?

Tags: lag, fps

I know some things about computers, but I'm not a computer expert. I have a decent computer with 8GB of memory, and a GTX 960. I usually have Curse, [Evolve](https://www.evolvehq.com/welcome), and Steam open.
(I've had **[this](http://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c02481322)** for a while, but this year I upgraded it with a better power supply, GTX 960, removed the 4*2GB of memory, and put in one 8GB of memory)

I've been playing Terraria, it used to play fine, always at 60fps. But now I'm usually at 45fps, I would be fine with that but it often goes down to something like 10fps for short (but often) times (Steam's fps counter doesn't say there is a change, but it's obvious there is stuttering). I have a few ideas on what's causing the problem, but I'm not sure on what it actually is. At the times the fps starts to go up and down, task manager says memory usage is around 6.5GB-7.0GB and CPU usage is around 80%. Does memory/CPU have to be 100% busy to cause lag, or can it just be close?

A program called "svchost.exe" is taking up ~1.7GB of memory and a lot of CPU (I think? not sure what the CPU column means in the task manager but it was a high number compared to everything else). I've read that svchost.exe is a windows process, but some viruses might use that name and I don't know how to tell. And if svchost.exe is legit, then does it only take up resources that are not being used or does my computer's svchost.exe have a problem?

**TL;DR:**
Does memory/CPU usage have to be at 100% to cause lag? Is svchost.exe taking up 1.7GB of memory and a lot of CPU a bad thing/a virus/fixable?

Comment: Have you done a virus scan?  What version of Windows?  Is it up to date?  Can you screenshot your processes?  I've encountered problems with svchost sucking things up, and figuring it out is a pain in the butt.  You could download a tool from Microsoft called process explorer and dig deeper in to the processes to try and figure what that svchost process is.

Comment: No, Windows 7, and it should be. I always close chrome if I have problems: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4d0OaFXWMxNUW1lUlZPeWsxWFU/view?usp=sharing). And sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

According o Microsoft "svchost.exe is a generic host process name for services that runs from dynamic-link libraries".

svchost.exe loads modules and program parts from .dll files to be used. As windows can't execute .dll files.

You can restart or stop some of these tasks in case of high cpu usage.

For this open **Task Manager** and click details tab.

Look for svchost.exe and see all services running on this name.

The best way to do it is to right-click on a svchost.exe service and select go to services. It will select all process running under it.

Read description of the service and stop the one that is of no use for now.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled some programs and that helped a bit, but it wasn't enough. Later, I accidently clicked on "create dump file" for scvhost.exe but canceled it while it was creating the file. Somehow, that seemed to fix my CPU problem because it immediately went from 60% down to 10%. After that, I cleared my cookies on Chrome, installed Ad-Block (only for websites that took up one whole GB or more because of ads), and installed a free trial for [Eset](http://www.eset.com/us/free-trial/?CMP=knc-inmkt-Google-G%7CS-US-BR-C-Other%7CB&gkw=%2Beset%20%2Bfree%20%2Btrial&gcr=79427028927&gcp239430327&gag=23327927007&gpl=&gclid=CJ_nxpzpzc0CFVE0aQodXv8J_Q) then scanned my computer. Eset said it didn't find any viruses, but my memory usage went down significantly and I can see all of the open processes (not from all users) on a single screen now. I haven't had any problems so far.

**TL;DR:** Uninstalled some programs. Started to create a dump file for scvhost.exe but canceled midway, bringing CPU down to 10%, then installed Ad-Block, [Eset](http://www.eset.com/us/free-trial/?CMP=knc-inmkt-Google-G%7CS-US-BR-C-Other%7CB&gkw=%2Beset%20%2Bfree%20%2Btrial&gcr=79427028927&gcp239430327&gag=23327927007&gpl=&gclid=CJ_nxpzpzc0CFVE0aQodXv8J_Q), and cleared cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The culpit of svchost.exe eating up memory is Windows update. Disable it and check if it becomes better. Also have a look at the info and comments here: http://www.file.net/process/svchost.exe.html